# Elasticsearch 1.1 IO Exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 1.1.2, but there are not so much examples for this version, so, I decided to make such first simple code:

http://pastebin.com/eVyL1mRr

But the result was like this (it was in wrong encoding):

```
java.io.IOException: ╙фрыхээ√щ їюёЄ яЁшэєфшЄхы№эю ЁрчюЁтры ёє∙хёЄтє■∙хх яюфъы■ўх
эшх
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)..........        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioW
orker.java:64)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.p
rocess(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
```